# Port forwarding https request to other server.

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, https, port-forwarding, troubleshooting

I've been asked to fix a  issue but I did not configure this server so I could not figure out what's happening here..

```
   www.mywebsite.com connects to 20.20.20.20 (Webserver)

   www.mywebsite.com:5487 connects to 10.10.10.10 (Webserver and replication DB), same copy of the 20.20 server webpages, apache version etc., and can be accessed only internally.
```

When connecting to https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html it connects to WEB server 20.20.20.20 and I see the request in the logs.

But when I try http://mywebsite.com:5487/index.html  it never loads and times out. There is  nothing on the error logs or access logs of that url request in 10.10.10.10 server. But RANDOMLY it loads (Once a week or sometimes for like 2 days it works fine). To fix this I wanted to know how its setup first....

There's no firewall. I don't see any config files related to that port number on apache and its not listening to port according to netstat. But when it loads randomly, I've checked netstat too and there's no port 5487 request.

How do you think they have configured web request to mywebsite.com on port 5487 to be forwarded to a different server? There's nothing on the network level.. There's no IP tables. I've just started looking into SSH based port forwarding. So far it looks like its not SSH based port forwarding too. Will update if I find anything.

Comment: Using Apache virtual-host ,could result in the above. Have you checked your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf  file?

Comment: Its centos. And I don't see any such files, I've checked for all config files for virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Apache to listen on the port 5487 with the command :

```
Listen 5487
```

and in your virtual host to set all directives you have to set

```
<VirtualHost *:5487>
```